# fetch data from sqlite and set it in text view from the spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

i'am facing a crash once i lunch the app, i'am trying to select value from a spinner and set it in text view. it was working fine without the spinner.
now its not working at all.
thank you in advance

Here is the Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
DB db;
Button addmed,addpl;
TextView PPLNAMERES;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new DB(this);
    ArrayList<String> my_array= new ArrayList<String>();
    my_array = db.getTableValues();
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> my_adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,my_array);
    spinner.setAdapter(my_adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    PPLNAMERES = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PPLAGETXTVIEW);
}


public void addmedView(View view){
    Intent ADDMEDVIEW = new Intent(this,ADDMEDCINEVIEW.class);
    startActivity(ADDMEDVIEW);

}
public void addpplview(View view){
    Intent ADDPPLVIEWS = new Intent(this,ADDPPLVIEW.class);
    startActivity(ADDPPLVIEWS);
}



public void listView(int index){
int getPPLNAME = index;
Cursor res= db.getMainData();
    if(res.moveToFirst()){
        PPLNAMERES.setText(res.getString(getPPLNAME));
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,    long id) {

    listView(position);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

the sqliteopenhelper class

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public final static String DBNAME = "MEDCINEDB.db";
public final static String Table_name = "MEDCINETable";
public final static String Table_name2 = "PPLTABLE";
public final static String col1 = "MEDCINEID";
public final static String col2 = "MEDCINENAME";
public final static String col3 = "MEDCINEPURPOSE";
public final static String col4 = "NOTAPLET";
public final static String col1T2 = "ID";
public final static String col2T2 = "NAMEPPL";
public final static String col3T2 = "AGEPPL";
public final static int DBVersion = 2;


public DB(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVersion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Table_name + "(MEDCINEID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,MEDCINENAME TEXT,MEDCINEPURPOSE TEXT,NOTAPLET INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Table_name2 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAMEPPL TEXT,AGEPPL INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF EXISTS" + Table_name);
    db.execSQL("DROP IF EXISTS" + Table_name2);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean inserData(String name, String purpose, String notaplet) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(col2, name);
    contentValues.put(col3, purpose);
    contentValues.put(col4, notaplet);

    long Result = db.insert(Table_name, null, contentValues);
    if (Result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean insertTb2Data(String Name, String Age) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues PPLcontentValues = new ContentValues();
    PPLcontentValues.put(col2T2, Name);
    PPLcontentValues.put(col3T2, Age);
    Long Result = db.insert(Table_name2, null, PPLcontentValues);
    if (Result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getMainData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select NAMEPPL from " + Table_name2, null);
    return result;

}

public ArrayList<String> getTableValues() {

    ArrayList<String> my_array = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor resultPPNAME = db.rawQuery("select NAMEPPL from " + Table_name2, null);
        resultPPNAME.moveToFirst();
        while (resultPPNAME.isAfterLast() == false) {
            String PPLNAMESPIN = resultPPNAME.getString(0);
            resultPPNAME.moveToNext();
            my_array.add(PPLNAMESPIN);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return my_array;

}
}
```

in the logcat show me this message

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Means `PPLAGETXTVIEW` TextView is not available in activity_main.xml layout ?

Comment: works fine but when i try to chose different value from the spinner crash in logcat show this message   Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `PPLNAMERES` TextView want to show selected text from Spinner then do it as by changing `listView` method as:

```
public void listView(int index){
  PPLNAMERES.setText(my_array.get(index));
}
```

Also declare `my_array` outside on create method same way as declared `PPLNAMERES` and other variables.